# How to shift the column header in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to Shift my Column header which is "
Subject No" to right. There should be no header in checkbox column.

[image]

The code for getting checkboxes is this ;

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow objRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TableCell tcCheckCell = new TableCell();
        CheckBox chkCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        tcCheckCell.Controls.Add(chkCheckBox);
        objRow.Cells.AddAt(0, tcCheckCell);

    }
}
```

I used DataTable to get the Data to GridView.

How to shift that colum header to right??

Thanks.

Comment: post the markup(.aspx page) code for your Gridview as well.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it in the wrong way, notice that you have an header column missing at the right.

instead of doing what you are doing now, try to simply add a new column at the very left and have no header text for it, then in the `ItemTemplate` of that first column you insert a `CheckBox`, this should do the trick without messing around the final generated table and in a much simpler way.

Comment: could you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a step missing in your GridView1_DataBound event; the rows collection that you iterate over only contains the data rows, you also need to add a new column to the header row. Insert the following line before your foreach loop and all will be well:

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.AddAt(0, new TableCell());
```

Answer (score 0):

To make header text empty for any particular column then you can use 
**BoundFiled** in asp:grid view to assign each headet text or make empty.
Like

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="SubjectNO" />
```